# Can't even create simplest android google maps. unknown error

Tags: android, google-maps

i am trying to learning google maps in android using Android Studio 3.1.3 and i have installed SDK 28. and my **build.gradle** file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    **implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'**
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and i dont know why but i am getting red line under "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

```
and i only did in this app is just added API key to it.

And My MainActivity.java looks like

package com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

and this is LOGCAT file

```
07-03 12:53:20.746 24521-24521/? I/.googlemapsdem: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-03 12:53:20.773 24521-24521/? W/.googlemapsdem: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
07-03 12:53:21.219 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/.googlemapsdem: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
07-03 12:53:21.220 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo I/chatty: uid=10103(com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo) identical 10 lines
07-03 12:53:21.220 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/.googlemapsdem: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
07-03 12:53:21.244 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-03 12:53:21.408 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
07-03 12:53:21.419 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/.googlemapsdem: Unsupported class loader
07-03 12:53:21.424 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:220
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 220
07-03 12:53:21.473 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/.googlemapsdem: Unsupported class loader
07-03 12:53:21.475 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/.googlemapsdem: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
07-03 12:53:21.503 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
07-03 12:53:21.510 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 12848026
07-03 12:53:21.636 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/.googlemapsdem: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
07-03 12:53:21.637 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo E/.googlemapsdem: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
07-03 12:53:21.834 24521-24548/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
07-03 12:53:21.966 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
07-03 12:53:22.055 24521-24573/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
07-03 12:53:22.055 24521-24573/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-03 12:53:22.055 24521-24573/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
07-03 12:53:22.056 24521-24573/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-03 12:53:22.056 24521-24573/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
07-03 12:53:22.079 24521-24573/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xdd5a3ec0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-03 12:53:22.089 24521-24573/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdd5a3ec0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe5f94840)
07-03 12:53:22.136 24521-24573/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdd5a3ec0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe5f94840)
07-03 12:53:22.155 24521-24569/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe0205fc0: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
07-03 12:53:22.171 24521-24569/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0205fc0: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xe02038f0)
07-03 12:53:23.266 24521-24548/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
    Process: com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo, PID: 24521
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at el.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):3)
        at ek.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):4)
        at em.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):51)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):11)
        at dw.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):16)
        at dw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):61)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/app_chimera/m/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):25)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at el.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):3) 
        at ek.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):4) 
        at em.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):51) 
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):11) 
        at dw.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):16) 
        at dw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):61) 
07-03 12:53:23.365 24521-24521/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
07-03 12:53:23.550 24521-24573/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdd5a3ec0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe5f94840)
07-03 12:53:23.974 24521-24571/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
07-03 12:53:23.991 24521-24571/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
07-03 12:53:23.995 24521-24571/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/.googlemapsdem: Unsupported class loader
07-03 12:53:24.007 24521-24571/com.example.kiran.googlemapsdemo W/.googlemapsdem: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
```

and my app is crashing again and again. please help me with this.

Comment: `and i dont know why but i am getting red line under "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'` hover with your mouse to see the warning emssage

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to your Android Manifest directly under your  tag fixes the issue you are facing if you are targeting API level 28 or higher.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"android:required="false"/>
```

Please refer this to [explore more about it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library.) 
Here's the issuetracker : [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779)

Answer (score 0):

Try this line instand of..

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

this line implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
not show preview of xml file code..

Answer (score 0):

solution:

Starting from Google Maps SDK version 16.1.0 you can skip adding the solution above as the tag has been added to the AndroidManifest of the maps library.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases#2019-02-06

Added the following declaration to the AndroidManifest.xml to support the Apache HTTP client on Android P and above. After updating to com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0 you can remove this line from your own AndroidManifest.xml. (Issue 117591497)